# Django wsgi - 504 when uploading big files

Tags: django, apache, file-upload, mod-wsgi

I have a Django app set up together with Apache and mod_wsgi. This app will serve pretty big files that will be uploaded by admins via the admin panel.

My problem is that big files (bigger than 15gb ish) triggers a 504 error when uploaded. The Apache error log reads:

`[Fri Feb 24 12:54:56.455187 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 18263] [client 2001:700:300:34:c9c3:2908:2c90:f44:52116] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'processName': /path/to/wsgi.py, referer: https:/mydomain.com/admin/appname/modelname/add/`

My understanding is that Django requires the entire file to be uploaded, before it sends a response. Because of the time it takes to upload the file, the process times out. With that said, the 504 errors is not triggered before the entire file is uploaded.

I have found others that have the same problem as me, but I have yet to find a solution to the problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I might make this work?

I have done a bit of reading on the [Django FileUploadHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/uploads/) class. Would it be possible to create a custom FileUploadHandler that responds to the request instantly, and then handles the upload asynchronously with Celery?

Comment: For a start, what mod_wsgi version are you using? Older versions may have limitations on file upload size and going over 2GB may trigger a possible bug. Is the file uploader class writing the file out to disk for later processing, or are you trying to process it on the fly?

Comment: I'm using mod_wsgi version 4.3.0. Atm I'm still using the standard Django FileHandlers (in this case `django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler` ).

Comment: Are you able to try with the latest mod_wsgi?

Comment: Just installed the latest version of mod_wsgi, and tried uploading a 46 GB file. Unfortunately I still get the same error.